# How can I know if a partition is mounted or unmounted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount

maybe this is a simple thing but I have the following doubt.

If I perform **fdisk -l**, in the output I can find these devices that represent 2 partitions on the **/dev/sdb** device that is my SD card:

```
Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          122880    15523839     7700480   83  Linux
```

From this output can I know is these partitions are mounted or unmounted ? (I think no).

What can I do to know if a specific partition is mounted on my system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mount` command is the usual way. On Linux, you can also check /etc/mtab, or /proc/mounts.

Comment: Note that `mount` simply displays the contents of `/etc/mtab`, which is a static file that can become out-of-date (most notably if the root fs is mounted read-only, but also if mounts are changed via direct syscalls rather than using the `mount` and `umount` utilities).  `/proc/mounts` is guaranteed to be accurate, but obviously only exists if the `/proc` filesystem is correctly mounted.  `df` reads `/etc/mtab` via the functions in `<mntent.h>`, so is no more reliable than this method.

Comment: @Jules, on some distros, `/etc/mtab` is actually a symlink to `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: @cjm I didn't know that; I'm a long-time debian/ubuntu user, where it isn't.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use `df`, which will give you a nicer printout and show the disk usage of the mounted file systems:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        27G  8.6G   17G  35% /
dev             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
run             2.0G  488K  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           2.0G  456K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.0G  738M  1.3G  38% /tmp
/dev/sdb2       715G  515G  164G  76% /home
tmpfs           396M  4.0K  396M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 13):

`lsblk` is a nice way **for humans** to see devices and mount-points. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/849364/108463).

```
$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk
└─dataGB-dataVB 253:1    0  14.6T  0 lvm  /mnt/dataB
sdb               8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─dataGB-dataVB 253:1    0  14.6T  0 lvm  /mnt/dataB
sdc               8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0   7.3T  0 part
  └─dataG-data  253:0    0   7.3T  0 lvm  /mnt/data
sdd               8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdd1            8:49   0   7.3T  0 part
sde               8:64   0   9.1T  0 disk
└─sde1            8:65   0   9.1T  0 part /mnt/dataC
nvme0n1         259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0 232.9G  0 part /
```

`findmnt` is useful **for scripting** or to query a specific device:

```
$ findmnt /dev/sde1
TARGET     SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/dataC /dev/sde1 xfs    rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
```

Comment: Best answer under my opinion. Displayed the exact information I needed, in a well-formatted way. +1

Comment: `findmnt`'s return value indicates if there was something found thus it can comfortably be used for checks, e.g., `findmnt --source "/dev/sdsomething" >"/dev/null" && ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could use the command **[blkid](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid)** to list what is mounted (DQMOT). I would suggest setting up your `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` - if you didn't know of it - with the outputs for the hard drives `blkid` picks up. The UUIDs "universally unique identifier" are a better way of mounting than other methods.

For example:

```
# <file system> <mount point>                   <type>  <options>                      <dump>  <pass>
UUID=9ee10f9f-c7fa-4c94-93dc-d8ca02db9c2f /     ext4    errors=remount-ro              0       1
UUID=48ee8-657-3154044569-d52005b00ded-68 none  swap    sw                             0       0
UUID=C8CE6F14CE6EF9D8 /media/john/windows       ntfs    defaults                       0       0
UUID=F4644D2D644CF3C0 /media/john/e             ntfs    defaults                       0       0
```

You can also often see in the file manager GUI: `win+e` and look at whether or not the disks are mounted with the up-turned arrows. You can also mount/un-mount from this menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this shows what's mounted, but not the device node, so it wouldn't answer the original question - how can I see which device nodes are actually mounted?

Is there a way of showing device nodes in this GUI?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use the command *mount*:

```
 $ mount
 /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
 proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
 none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
 none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
 none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
 udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
 devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
 tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
 none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
 none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
 none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
 none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
 /dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
 binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
 rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
 systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

This information is stored in /etc/mtab, you can see by yourself that the output of *mount* is nearly identical to that of /etc/mtab

Answer (score 1):

How about **gnome-disks**? Depending on the Ubuntu release, it appears in classic menus as **Disks** under either **Accessories** or **Utilities**?

It gives a graphical map of each disc unit and full details of device name, size, mount status, etc, and also allows mount/dismount. It has the advantage over **mount** of showing both mounted and unmounted partitions, but as a GUI program it does not have an output that can be piped to other processes in a script. Unlike **blkid** it does not need root priveleges.